Usage of 'convalesce' as a transitive verb
Would something akin to the following parse?
"Over time, the regimen successfully convalesced the patient."
None of the examples given in definitions of the word I can find using dictionaries utilize the word in this way, but it seems to make sense to me. It also seems to have slightly different connotations than
"Over time, the regimen successfully healed/cured/helped the patient."

If the references don't use it that way, that would suggest that it isn't used that way.

Cured, healed, helped, or improved the condition of would be better.

The full Oxford English Dictionary only defines it a intransitive. There are no definitions or examples of transitive use.

Cured, healed, helped, or improved seem not to have precisely the same connotation as convalesced to me?

This question is of the form "Dictionaries define this word one way, but I think a different usage makes sense. Would that work?" The obvious answer is "No, unless you're being deliberately creative/inventive and your audience understands what you're trying to achieve." Since that answer applies to just about any novel or weird personal word usage, such a question really doesn't belong on this site. It certainly doesn't warrant reopening after it's been closed. You might like to check our [Tour] page to get a better sense of how our site works. :-)

Protologisms (and by extension D-I-Y new meanings for existing words) are off-topic on ELU, as Chappo Who Has A Good Memory says. There is the occasional transitive usage of 'convalesce' to be seen on the internet, but then there are quite a few pseudowords out there too. Dictionary acceptance is the usual test for wordness, though use in a respected journal say is also a reasonable test. This usage fails these tests as far as I can see.

The OP's wishing to use the word this way may be a manifestation of a wider tendency among medical practitioners to use the forms of language that emphasise the passivity of their patients (as the very word patient does); see, for example "Consent" in passive voice to refer to subject giving consent?.

"She's taking her boy to Loring next week, to convalesce him."   Swan Song, John Galsworthy.  Though I think Galsworthy obtained the sole and exclusive rights to use the verb transitively.

Online, Merriam-Webster, Collins, Cambridge, and dictionary.com all define convalesce solely as intransitive. The OED also lists it as solely intransitive (Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “convalesce (v.),” June 2024, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/6164890990.)
Therefore it is strictly speaking incorrect to use it as a transitive verb. The title asks about its use as a transitive verb, so that's the answer.
However, the question body asks "does it parse", and it's entirely possible to parse a sentence even if it's gibberish: example, "He fooed his dog" has a fairly obvious structure even if you don't know what the made-up verb foo means.
If you used "convalesce" transitively to mean "cause to convalesce", then people could parse it and probably guess what you mean. Other verbs like heal (Merriam-Webster) can be used both transitively ("The treatment healed him") and intransitively ("He healed from the illness"). I would not depend on any specific differences in meaning: intransitively to heal and to convalesce don't mean the same thing, with the former meaning something like "to cure completely" and the latter "to rest and recover". But if you're using a made-up word or a word in a made-up context, you can't rely on people either knowing the distinction or being able to look it up: they'll get the general sense but not know if you meant anything more precise.
